# Ubuntu 16.04 Unity GUI slow performance

Tags: 16.04, uefi, performance, windows-10, secure-boot

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my SSD in dual boot aside of Windows 10 and I can't use it because the GUI is really slow. Previously I have installed Ubuntu on my  `sdb`(hard drive rather than SSD) but the GUI was really slow. Then I decided to install it on my SSD but I have the same problem. I believe I have a good PC and here are the specs:

- Intel I7 6700k Quad Core processor
- Nvidia Geforce 1070 GTX.
- 16 GB RAM

...

I tried to install Arch Linux too last time but I have the same problem. Then I don't think the problem is just on Ubuntu.

During the installation, I can choose if I want to turn off the UEFI secure boot and set a password. But if I do that I have an warning message. This message said that if I choose this option it's possible that I can't boot on other operators system currently installed. Then I didn't choose this option because I need to keep windows.

So maybe I should choose this option on the installation to fix this problem ?

What is wrong ?

Comment: I think you need a proprietary driver for your nvidia card. If you search AskUbuntu for *Nvidia 1070*, you will find several questions and answers, that might help you.

Comment: I will suggest you create a rescue drive for your Windows O/S or at least a recovery partition. Then you can try installing Ubuntu with secure boot off.

Comment: Ok first I'll try to install Nvidia drivers. After I'll check how can I create a rescue drive

Comment: Ohhh after installing Nvidia Drivers it works  !! :D.  Thanks ! I think this problem is caused by the secure boot during the installation :/ Ubuntu doesn't install drivers because I didn't choose the option to turn off secure boot

Comment: @sudodus you might want to put an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score -1):

[UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi?lq=1) Strikes Again!

Specifically the SECURE BOOT Option as explained in the AskUbuntu Community Wiki link above. PCs implementing support for SECURE BOOT only became widespread in 2012 and it is possible that you will encounter problems booting Ubuntu under SECURE BOOT. -paraphrased from Luis Alvarado in the above UEFI link

My research on this matter is based in AskUbuntu, Nvidia, and various bugs listed on Github.

"Since Ubuntu kernel 4.4.0-20 the EFI_SECURE_BOOT_SIG_ENFORCE kernel config has been enabled. That prevents from loading unsigned third party modules if UEFI Secure Boot is enabled." -Pilot6

The Nvidia drivers are considered unsigned third party modules. - derived from [Nvidia](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.32/README/installdriver.html)

"The easiest way to fix this issue is to disable Secure Boot in UEFI (BIOS) settings." -Pilot6

[Github](https://gist.github.com/kdzlvaids/6d05d552ef4f39bdd08176909e5cbb31) may also point to some of the troubles you experienced.